# UK Visa decided but no email received

Tags: visas, uk

I've been monitoring my Tier2 UK visa on the tracker available online and my application reached the step 'Application sent to VAC' a week ago but till now I haven't received an email claiming that a decision has been made.
I've sent the DMC an email and they confirmed that a decision has been taken. Is it normal not to receive an email? Does that mean that my application was rejected? VAC hasn't contacted me yet either and unfortunately there is noway I can reach out to them.

Comment: Not receiving an email does not mean your visa is rejected, the same way as receiving an email doesn't mean it was accepted.